# How and where to call post_migrate where Django's own Permission model is the sender

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

In my current project I want to use Django Group model objects as access roles.
I'm trying to programmatically assign permissions to the group instances that should have them (for example, 'delete_something' for 'moderator', and Permission.objects.all() for 'admin') during migration, but even though the code runs without errors, not all permissions are assigned. Specifically, no permissions against User model are assigned. The model itself is defined in a separate application (custom User model from my 'users' app).

Theoretically, this code should kick in when migration is finished and all models are registered. It would then create required groups (I'm using default Django's Group model) and assign permissions to them (also using default Permission instances that are created by Django for each model).
After reading a few similar questions, I have a guess that it must be connected to either the order of migrations, the fact that the User model is defined outside of the app that my code is called, or something specific to Permissions migration.

Currently, my code runs from the AppConfig class of one of my project's apps that contains most of the models, and is called by its ready() function.

I wonder if that is the right place to call that code.
I also think that it would make sense for Permission model to be the signal sender, but I don't understand at what point I should be able to call it (when it is registered/ready) and from which part of my project?
If that is connected to User residing in a different app, how do I make the post_migrate run only after both apps are ready? What should it listen for?

I attach my current **apps.py** code below.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate


class ReviewsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'reviews'
    verbose_name = name.capitalize()

    def setup_permissions(self, sender, **kwargs) -> None:
        """Get and set permissions for the groups that should have them."""
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
        from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

        Review = self.get_model('Review')
        Comment = self.get_model('Comment')

        # get all auto-generated permissions for Review and Comment models

        review_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Review))
        comment_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Comment))

        # create new groups if DoesNotExist and assign respective permissions

        Group.objects.get_or_create(name='user')

        moderators, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="moderator")
        if not created:
            moderator_permissions = (
                list(filter(
                    lambda perm: perm.codename in (
                        'delete_review',
                        'change_review'),
                    review_permissions))
                + list(filter(
                    lambda perm: perm.codename in (
                        'delete_comment',
                        'change_comment'),
                    comment_permissions))
            )
            moderators.permissions.add(*moderator_permissions)

        admins, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="admin")
        if not created:
            admins.permissions.set(Permission.objects.all())

    # run the permissions setup only when migration is finished

    def ready(self) -> None:

        post_migrate.connect(self.setup_permissions, sender=self)
        return super().ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `save()` after the instance is created.

Comment: Hi! Could you clarify which instance should be saved?
As far as I am aware, get_or_create calls save() behind the scenes by itself, and auth_group table is created in the DB with both 'user', 'moderator', 'admin' groups.
The problem is that they're not assigned any permissions.